# HighCharts areaspline multicolor gradient opacity fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I'm trying to accomplish a top-down fade effect for an areaspline chart except with multiple colors.

Here is what I have so far:
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aTmK.png)

I'm trying to mimic this:
[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD3rP.png)

Comment: can you inspect the html markup of the area where the colors are not on opacity, not the splines. just the colored area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change option in your series:

```
series: [{
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: {
                linearGradient : {
                    x1: 1,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 0
                },
                stops : [
                    [0, Highcharts.Color('#FC4474').setOpacity(1).get('rgba')],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color('#5D48A1').setOpacity(1).get('rgba')],
                ]
            },
            fillColor : {
                linearGradient : {
                    x1: 1,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops : [
                    [0, Highcharts.Color('#FC4474').setOpacity(0.7).get('rgba')],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color('#5D48A1').setOpacity(0).get('rgba')],
                ]
            }
        }]
```

Comment: That just changes the opacity of the grid lines. Im trying to create the fading effect for the area under the line from semi-transparent to completely transparent.

Comment: what version are you using? im using hc 4.1.10. i edited my answer. try to check again

Comment: I'm using v4.2.1. Maybe it's not working because I have the fill color defined as a linear gradient?

Comment: how can we set Three color as gradient lets say Red, Green and Yellow